# Retrieve data from parse.com and populate a textfield

Tags: android, parse-platform, displayobject

This is doing my head in. I got this working in iOS in about 10 mins. Clearly I'm missing something. I'm simply trying to pull data out of parse.com into a textfield. I have found lots of examples but none explaining why it's not working correctly. Below is the code pulled from parse.com site and jiggyed with. Incidentally it's wigging out on totemList.getString particularly the "getString" part.

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Birds");
           query.whereEqualTo("totemName", "Pigeon");
           query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
               public void done(List<ParseObject> totemList, ParseException e) {
                   if (e == null) {
                       Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + totemList.size() + " scores");
                       String totemDesc = totemList.getString("totemDesc");
                       //Get the Totems Description
                       TotemDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.animalDesc);
                       TotemDescription.setText(totemDesc);
                   } else {
                       Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                       // something went wrong
                       TotemDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.animalDesc);
                       TotemDescription.setText("not bob");
                   }
               }
           });
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: cannot resolve method 'getString(java.lang.String);

Comment: BTW hector this is directly off of the parse.com site and no animals were harmed in coding this...

Comment: Can you post a link to the specific doc that has this code sample?

Comment: Hi Hector, no worries. It's in the Docs section saving objects( "retrieve objects" https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide. The only thing I changed was  clearly the table I was hiding and "findInBackground" rather then "getInBackground". HTH. I'm about to attempt to pull an image out of parse for android now...no doubt I will be back with more questions..hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[List<>](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) does not have a getString() method.

```
List<ParseObject> totemList
```

Perhaps what you wanted to do was to iterate over your list of ParseObject get all the descriptions:

```
String descriptions = null;
for (ParseObject totem : totemList) {
    if (descriptions == null) {
        descriptions = totem.getString("totemDesc");
    } else {
        descriptions = descriptions + ", " + totem.getString("totemDesc");
    }
}
```

Something like that. Then set the resulting string as text of your text field

```
TotemDescription.setText(descriptions);
```

If you have more than one ParseObject in your List<> your text will be something like:

```
Pigeon Totem, Another Pigeon Totem
```

Comment: Hi Marat, I just read that as your answer came up. Why would they use it on the example site if that were not the case? If List<> should not be used what should be? In iOS it's a Simple PFObject then you just ask the object for the specific attribute you want. i.e. out of the row of data give me the "name" or give me the "description".

Comment: Well a List<> is just an ordered collection of elements - in your case [ParseObject](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html). Seems like what the callback gives you is a collection of these elements, and you can call [getString("totemDesc")](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getString(java.lang.String)) on each one to get your descriptions.

Comment: So you mean calling it directly in the TextView call? Is this what you mean? Do you have an example of what your suggesting?

Comment: Makes logical sense to me the way you suggested but still crashed. Only this time didn't give me any warnings...

Comment: Take a look at your LogCat output to see where the crash/problem is, and go on from there. Unfortunately I can't really tell you much more without having further insight into your project, and what the crash is.

Comment: HAHAHA totally agree logcat was completely empty. I'm working on restarting entire project to see if I can catch the error.

Comment: Okay got it to error without crashing. I get "java.lang.NullPointerException" which points to this line. TotemDescription.setText(descriptions);

Comment: Der...I forgot to add in TotemDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.animalDesc);

Comment: Working now perfectly! Thanks mate. Points gone to you.